# How can I have my device charge only when battery is below a given percentage?

Tags: battery, nexus-7, charging

So I've mounted my Nexus 7 onto a wall and use it as a sort of info screen / home automatisation device. Now this would require the screen to be on all the time which is why I want it to be connected to a charging cable 24/7.

Is there a way I can make the device start charging when the battery level falls below 10%? I don't want it to be charging all the time as this would wear off the battery pretty quickly.

I don't have root access.

Answer (score 1):

No, It is not possible on unrooted devices and yes, it can be done on rooted devices.

In a rooted device,

Add a permission to Android : `android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS.`

Then, system call the set function of the `BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING`
from the `BatteryManager` with a 0 value.

To automate this function, use a third-party application like [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) to set a trigger on `Battery % < 10` to do the forementioned system call.

Comment: Hey. My phone is rooted however I'm kind of a noob and I have no clue of where to input those command lines. Help?